# How to delete in file 1 which is not in file 2

Tags: linux, csv, bioinformatics

I have 2 files; file1 and file2. File1 has many lines/rows and columns. File2 has just one column, with several lines/rows. All of the strings in file2 are found in file1. I want to create a new file (file3),

For example,

File1:

```
Sally ate 083 popcorn

Rick has 241 cars

John won 505 dollars

Bruce knows 121 people
```

File2:

```
083
121
```

Desired file3:

```
Sally ate 083 popcorn
Bruce knows 121 people
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `grep -f`:

```
$ cat file1
Sally ate 083 popcorn
Rick has 241 cars
John won 505 dollars
Bruce knows 121 people
$ cat file2
083
121
$ grep -f file2 file1
Sally ate 083 popcorn
Bruce knows 121 people
```

To save the output in file3:

```
grep -f file2 file1 > file3
```